# gnustep with appkit dpi issue when loading nsimage

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit, gnustep

I'm using objc code which run both on mac and linux.
on mac i use xcode for compiling and on linux i use GNUstep. (code is the same)

i got issue regarding the dpi.

i use the following code to check image dpi

```
     NSBitmapImageRep* rep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:[image TIFFRepresentation]];
  NSSize pointsSize = rep.size;
        NSSize pixelSize = NSMakeSize(rep.pixelsWide, rep.pixelsHigh);

        CGFloat currentDPI = ceilf((72.0f * pixelSize.width)/pointsSize.width);
        NSLog(@"result DPI %f pointSize(%dx%d) , pixelSize(%dx%d)", currentDPI,(int)pointsSize.width,(int)pointsSize.height,(int)rep.pixelsWide,(int)rep.pixelsHigh);
```

for the exact same image i'm getting different values on both operation systems

on mac
*result DPI 600.000000 pointSize(51x51) , pixelSize(429x429)*

on linux
*result DPI 72.000000 pointSize(429x429) , pixelSize(429x429)*

my main issue is after the image has been manipulated it's saved with lower dpi then the orginal image.

i guess that could be fixed by code only thing is i don't know how to get the real dpi value from the NSImage object on linux...

Is it some kind of issue in at AppKit implementation ?